# How to disable auto-sleep in Windows 8.1 throughly?

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, tablet

I have tablet with windows 8.1, and I set it to never sleep, but sometimes when I lock it, it will sleep after about 2 hours... How to let it not sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable sleep in:

> Control Panel > System > Power Options > Change Plan > Put Computer to Sleep

set to `Never`, for more info see [this page](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=30).

If above not worked, try solution from [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6e4ca5ef-c483-499c-b68f-856fb68d8867/monitors-turn-off-after-being-locked-for-one-minute?forum=w8itprogeneral), it says:

> at first you must set value of **Attributes** = dword: 00000002 in
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7]
>
> and then in  **Power Options** > **Advanced Power Settings** in the **Display** item appears **Console lock display off timeout** in which we set the **necessary time**.

Comment: Thank you, it worked sometime but then reversed to default automatically. Now I just fully disabled lock screen app by gpedit, and the problem is solved.

Comment: @Sam Glad it helped. (upvote if you think answer was useful)